# Uneven Custom PSObjects in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that includes four custom PSObjects that display usernames and the groups they are currently members of.  It takes the user's main username and uses that to search for their elevated and admin account names.  It then takes those and adds them to custom PSObjects, but the results are uneven and not lined up as one would expect as in below.

This is what I have so far:

```
$userName = (Read-Host "New Username").Trim()
$elev = "elev_$userName"
$admin = "admin_$userName"

$members = @()

foreach ($mem in $(((Get-ADUser "$elev" -Properties *).memberof) -replace ",OU=.*", '' -replace 'CN=', '' | Sort-Object)) {
    $members += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'elev_User'="$elev"; 'elev_Membership'="$mem"}
}

foreach ($mem in $(((Get-ADUser "$admin" -Properties *).memberof) -replace ",OU=.*", '' -replace 'CN=', '' | Sort-Object)) {
    $members += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'admin_User'="$admin"; 'admin_Membership'="$mem"}
}

$members | Select-Object elev_User, elev_Membership, admin_Membership, admin_User
```

Currently I'm getting the following output:

```
elev_User   elev_Membership admin_Membership admin_User
---------   --------------- ---------------- ----------
elev_bob    group1
elev_bob    group2
elev_bob    group3
                            group1           admin_bob
                            group6           admin_bob
                            group190         admin_bob
```

But, I want it to be:

```
elev_User   elev_Membership admin_Membership admin_User
---------   --------------- ---------------- ----------
elev_bob    group1          group1           admin_bob
elev_bob    group2          group6           admin_bob
elev_bob    group3          group190         admin_bob
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to do is join both arrays for admin and elevated membership, for that you can use a `for` loop, I would suggest to also include the input `$userName` in your output to have a reference:

```bash
$userName = (Read-Host 'New Username').Trim()
$elev = "elev_$userName"
$admin = "admin_$userName"
$elevMembership = @((Get-ADUser $elev -Properties memberof).memberof)
$adminMembership = @((Get-ADUser $admin -Properties memberof).memberof)

$result = for($i = 0; $i -lt [math]::Max($elevMembership.Count, $adminMembership.Count); $i++) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        UserName         = $userName
        elev_User        = $elev
        elev_Membership  = $elevMembership[$i]
        admin_User       = $admin
        admin_Membership = $adminMembership[$i]
    }
}

$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: That works great.  Though I see that it does it all in a list.  Is there a way to make them into columns?  The reason I want it to display in that manner is because I want to be able to easily compare the membership of each user.

Comment: @pyqaqeka ah yeah thats because objects with 5 or more properties are displayed as a list by default in powershell, you can however use `Format-Table` here, see my update